# Xamarin Debugger not attaching in Xamarin Android Project

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I have a installation of Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition with Xamarin. I just created a new PCL Project and wanted to debug the application. But to my surprise, when I debug the Xamarin Android Project,my breakpoints don't hit at all.

I compared it with my another installation at my office place where the debugger does work. In this installation, once the build and deploy succeeds, the debugger is attached. I say this because the ribbon control at top to start the android emulator is grayed out.

But in the problematic installation, its not grayed out. It shows build and deployed succeeded in the Output windows. Then , in the status bar it shows Start Debugging Android Application, followed by Debugging Android Application. Then the debugger doesn't attach (as the ribbon control is enabled at the end)

[image: Enabled ribbon control after deploy succeeded.]

Note: I have selected the Xamarin Debugger in the Android projects Debugging options.

Any help regarding this will be appreciated. :D

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and no solution to it :(

Comment: Run vs in admin mode, then deploy to emulator.  After that it should be fine.  I think.

Comment: I'm searching for a different emulator issue...but if you have an environment difference, can you confirm the regedit is pointing to your SDK folder? this seemed to solve a related issue other people were having.

Comment: Hi.. Did you find any solution for this issue..Not able to attach debugger.